# WordPress is disabling HTTPS. How is it doing it and how do I stop it?

Tags: ssl, https, wordpress

WordPress redirecting my site from `HTTPS` to `HTTP`. I'm able to access direct files (e.g. `.jpg`, `.html`) with `HTTPS` or `HTTP` as I choose. But any time I load a WordPress page of any kind, it switches to `HTTP`.

I know that it's not being done in the `.htaccess` file because the behavior does not change even when I delete everything in the file. I also tried to force `HTTPS` via `.htaccess` using the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However this results in a redirect loop!

I have also tried to enable [administration over SSL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL) with this:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

and this:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

But in both cases, all that happens is the entire admin area of WordPress breaks.

I've also tried installing the [WordPress HTTPS (SSL)](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin, but it also just breaks the entire admin section completely.

I do have iThemes Security installed, but I haven't messed with the SSL section at all. It's hosted on an Apache server with WHM/cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

In Settings -> General there are two fields with the url for your website (WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL).

[image]
Are they set to http or https? If they are set to http change them to https and save the changes. That should fix the problem.

Comment: They were `http`. I just switched them to `https`, but everything seems to be exactly the same, besides that it logged me out of WordPress and I had to log back in.

Comment: You might need to do a hard refresh or try private browsing (or another browser).

Comment: No dice, even on a different operating system.